# Pin custom tile to Windows 10 start menu

Tags: wpf, windows-10, startmenu

I'd like to pin a custom tile to the start menu and launch a website or desktop file when I click on it. There's an app called Better start menu, but it has to keep running and not the best experience.

Can I just place some HTML/XML markup at a specific location and it gets displayed?

[image]